# Android get an error add SlidingMenu to project in ecslipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sliding

after downloading jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu project from GitHub and import that to Eclipse, i'm created new project into eclipse and i want to add that to `Projects` and as library into `Android` section i get this error after `Apply` and `OK` :

```
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] Versions found are:
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] Path: /home/tux-world/workspace/library/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1]    Length: 385685
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1]    SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] Path: /home/tux-world/workspace/SlideMenuSample1/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1]    Length: 758727
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-10-05 12:22:20 - SlideMenuSample1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

i'm try to resolve this problem but i can not do it. whats problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have two different version of android-support-v4.jar one in your project, one in lib project. Thing what you do is not delete one of them, but go to Java Build Path menu ->  Orders and Export and check android-support-v4.jar that you want to use in your project and uncheck otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have two same `android-support-v4.jar`. In `SlidingMenu` lib folder you have additional `android-support-v4.jar` just delete it.After you delete on of them clean and rebuild project.